# Why doesn't Perl print this message and exit?

Tags: perl

OK:

```
my $login='anybody';
exit if $login ne 'root';
```

NOT OK: Why doesn't the following print "`error`"?

```
my $login='anybody';
(print "error" && exit) if $login ne 'root';
```

I know about if (condition) {action}. I just want to know about current problem.

Comment: What does "NOT OK" mean? It does something unexpected? It throws a warning/error?

Comment: Actually, Brian, in Perl it does. We use, for example, `open(stuff) || die "error"` for all sorts of error checking, just like in bash scripting.

Comment: @Dan - I deleted to comment and moved it to an answer to fully explain. It's a logical comparison which *does* control whether or not things are executed, but it's still not "And then do this", especially the way to OP's code is written.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because what you have written says:

"print the evaluation of the string 'error' and the result of the command exit"

You could actually write:

```
((print "error\n") && exit) if $login ne 'root';
```

But please don't. :)

Comment: I actually removed it thinking it was too tongue and cheek. I rolled back :)

Comment: Why yes I did. Unfortunately my brain is often out of sync with my fingers.

Comment: It's okay.  It's a doggy dog world out there, and you have to take some things with a grain assault.

Answer (score 9):

There are three problems.

---

The first problem, the one you ask about, is one of precedence.

```
print "error" && exit if ...;
```

is the same as

```
print("error" && exit) if ...;
```

Possible fixes:

```
(print "error") && exit if ...;
print("error") && exit if ...;
print "error" and exit if ...;
```

---

The second problem is that `exit` is conditional on the result of `print`, and that's not appropriate. You want to exit even if `print` returns an error.

Possible fixes:

```
(print "error"), exit if ...;
print("error"), exit if ...;
```

---

The third problem is that this is a really poor way of reporting an error. Errors should be printed on `STDERR` and a non-zero exit code should be used. [`die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) would work great here.

```
die "error" if ...;
```

Comment: +1 for highlighting the second problem, which solves the issue from the root

Comment: Zaid was referring to what is now the third problem.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect that you aren't seeing "error" printed, correct? That's because the expression `print "error" && exit` is interpreted as `print ("error" && exit)`. Try this instead:

```
do { print "error"; exit } if $login ne 'root';
```

Comment: Good guess - but we shouldn't *have* to guess.  The question should be stated more clearly.  IMHO...

Comment: But `perldoc perlop` says that named unary operators have higher precedence than `&&`, so it should be interpreted as `(print "error") && exit`.

Comment: @Dan - `print` isn't a named unary operator. It's a function.

Comment: @Dan, It is an operator, but it's a "list operator". ("Unary" means "single argument", so `print` isn't unary.) List operators have "either very high or very low depending on whether you are looking at the left side or the right side of the operator." Commas on the right of a list operator are evaluated before the operator.

Comment: That should be "`&&`" instead of "Commas" in my last comment.